# Offset VBA Range based upon leftmost cell

Tags: vba, excel, offset

I would like to copy all data to the right of a cell and paste it 3 cells to the right of the first selected cell. I am using the following code, but it keeps on jumping 3 columns to the right of the end of the selection.

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Cut
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Is there a way to use the first cell of the selection as the reference for the shift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Cut ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That got me on the right track. What I used in the end was just a paste step in between and instead of pastespecial it was select.
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: Already done so! Maybe just add the code I used, to show the additional select and paste steps. The PasteSpecial didn't work for me.

Comment: Done. As soon as I get by any PC I’ll post a solution without all that “selections”

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've understood correctly, but aren't you just inserting three cells to the right at the ActiveCell?

How about this instead?

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```